# LuaLaTeX Manual Hyphenation not working

Tags: luatex, hyphenation

i globally declared the hyphenation of a word like this

```
\hypenation{dis-tri-bu-tion-point-objekt}
```

The Word is a mix of english an german (the last part objekt is in german language). But the word will not be separated and so it goes out of box and lays on the right space of the letter and not in the next line.

I tried it also manually with `\=` but then LuaLaTeX prints out the two characters in the text.

I'm using `lualatex`, so where is the problem? thanks!

**EDIT**
Added MWE.

```
\documentclass[%
a4paper,
12pt,                           
DIV=calc,                   
oneside,
parskip=half,       
captions=nooneline,
numbers=noenddot, 
listof=totocnumbered,
bibliography=totocnumbered
]
{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}


\begin{document}
Die Erweiterung besteht aus einer Sequenz von DistributionPoint-Objekten. Das Distribution-Point-Objekt wiederum besteht aus drei optionalen Feldern distributionPoint, reasons und cRLIssuer. Allerdings darf das Objekt nicht nur auf dem reasons-Feld bestehen. Es muss entweder das Feld distributionPoint oder cRLIssuer vorhanden sein. Allerdings darf das Objekt nicht nur auf dem reasons-Feld bestehen. Es muss entweder das Feld distributionPoint oder cRLIssuer vorhanden sein. Allerdings darf das Objekt nicht nur auf dem reasons-Feld bestehen. Es muss entweder das Feld distributionPoint oder cRLIssuer vorhanden sein. Allerdings darf das Objekt nicht nur auf dem reasons-Feld bestehen. Es muss entweder das Feld distributionPoint oder cRLIssuer vorhanden sein.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you specify

```
\hyphenation{dis-tri-bu-tion-point=objekt}
```

in the preamble, the German language has not yet been loaded. You have to delay this at begin document. Note `=` to denote a `-` in the word.

```
\documentclass[%
a4paper,
12pt,
DIV=calc,
oneside,
parskip=half,
captions=nooneline,
numbers=noenddot,
listof=totocnumbered,
bibliography=totocnumbered
]
{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}

\begin{document}
\hyphenation{dis-tri-bu-tion-point=objekt}

Die Erweiterung besteht aus einer Sequenz von DistributionPoint-Objekten.
Das DistributionPoint-Objekt wiederum besteht aus drei optionalen Feldern
distributionPoint, reasons und cRLIssuer.

\end{document}
```

[image]

A way for adding the hyphenations in the preamble, in multiple languages and avoiding `\selectlanguage` that has the defect of writing things in the auxiliary files.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newcommand{\sethyphenation}[2]{%
  \begin{otherlanguage*}{#1}\hyphenation{#2}\end{otherlanguage*}%
}

\sethyphenation{german}{dis-tri-bu-tion-point=objekt}
\sethyphenation{english}{as-df-gh-jkl}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{DistributionPoint-Objekt}

\bigskip

\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
\parbox{0pt}{asdfghjkl}
\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}
```

The `\parbox{0pt}` is just to show hyphenations.

[image]

If you want a break also after the explicit hyphen, you can do

```
\sethyphenation{german}{dis-tri-bu-tion-point={}{}{}objekt}
```

Here's the output in this case

[image]

Comment: great. the `=`did the trick. Can i place the `\hypenation` command before `\begin{document}`?

Comment: @Opa114 I tried a few ways, but only `\AtBeginDocument{\hyphenation{...}}` works, which would be quite bad for documents in multiple languages. `:(` I'll try something more.

Comment: @egreg: You should activate the language: `\selectlanguage{german}
\hyphenation{dis-tri-bu-tion-point=objekt}` then it will work in the preamble too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @egreg no problem for me; both ways are working and that is enough for me :)

Comment: @Opa114 I added a macro for setting hyphenations in the preamble.

Comment: @egreg why? polyglossia activates the " anyway.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't like writing in the aux file if not necessary; since it's possible with `otherlanguage*`, it's better.

Comment: You can also use \hyphenrules{german}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Unfortunately, no. With Polyglossia it chooses the wrong variant of German.

Comment: Sorry I meant `\hyphenrules{ngerman}` (I really shouldn't run three tests for different projects at the same time).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That would work, but of course the `hyphenrules` environment should be fixed to use the language selected with `\setmainlanguage` or `\setotherlanguage`.